# When is the Jungle Book set?

Tags: the-jungle-book-2016, the-jungle-book-1967

I'm trying to arrange my DVDs in order of when they are set, and I was just wondering, when is the Jungle Book set? The book was written in 1892, but that seems too modern for the setting shown in both films.

Comment: Arranging your DVDs in order of fictional dates?  Are you planning to watch a very fictionalized movie history of the world by watching all your DVDs in fictional order?  That would be interesting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The events of the movie could really happen any time in the past 1000 years.  I looked at the books for a mention of technology that would help place the events in time..

[Tiger, Tiger](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/k/kipling/rudyard/jungle/chapter5.html) recounts the events that happen after Mowgli enters the human village.  In it is mentioned a musket.

> It was the village club, and the head-man and the watchman and the
>   barber, who knew all the gossip of the village, and old Buldeo, the
>   village hunter, who had a Tower musket, met and smoked...

Looking up Tower musket I found:

> Judging from this material, your rifle is a British Enfield 1853
>   pattern rifle-musket that was made or assembled at the Tower of
>   London, England, in 1860. The crown denotes British government
>   ownership.... It was well made and deadly
>   accurate.
>   https://www.americanrifleman.org/articles/2014/3/11/tower-enfield-musket/

A British firearm makes sense in India of the 1800s.  A man in a poor Indian village would not have had a valuable or late model rifle.

Also supporting this are the man made ruins where the monkeys live.  If these events happened 1000 years earlier or in prehistoric times I don't think the ruins would have looked like they did.

I conclude that the events of the written story probably happened about the time they were written in 1892.

Comment: Great answer from a couple of small details